# Eliminating duplicates in a data frame works, but when I save the CSV and reload it, more duplicates appear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, duplicates

I have this big DataFrame with around 9 million rows. I want to eliminate all duplicate rows, and I do so by using drop_duplicates(), which is fine until I save the new file to disk and reload it.

[image: Code used]

Can you help me understand what is going on here? Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: What kind of data is this?  Are these float values, so you're getting round-off errors?  Do they contain extra quote marks?  Have you looked at the duplicated rows to see what is confusing things?

Comment: Is it possible you have non-ASCII characters in there, and you're saving it in a character set that doesn't preserve the values?

Comment: check `ndf` individual columns, most likely these dupes pop out in the same column or two, so work /clean  these cols on the original data before removing dupes

Comment: In any case, please provide a small sample of the data for reproducibility